# Mesh data in FEM format in Ansys Workbench

Tags: geometry, ansys, comsol

I am using Ansys workbench2020R2.I want to get mesh data of a deformed geometry in FEM format. Is there any way to get the mesh data in FEM format in Ansys workbench?
Deformed geometry was created by applying time varying load.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities to get to the deformed mesh are described in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67699891/13974897